# tmpfs is slower when accessing a single file than accessing multiple files

Tags: tmpfs

Reading different (1.6 GB) blocks of the *same* file stored on `tmpfs` maxes out at 2.5GB/s at around 20 threads:

[image]

But if the same blocks are split into different files on `tmpfs` I can get 22GB/s:

[image]

What is causing this bottleneck? Is there a way I can make `tmpfs` work as fast on a single file as it works on multiple files?

**To reproduce**

It is much easier to look at writing than reading, but the problem and the speed difference is similar:

```
$ cd /mnt/tmpfs
$ cores=$(seq 64)
$ # -u disables GNU Parallel's on-disk buffer
$ time parallel -n0 -u  'yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M' ::: $cores > 100g

real    3m54.286s
user    1m10.592s
sys     246m42.804s

$ time parallel 'yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > {#}' ::: $cores

real    0m26.308s
user    1m21.283s
sys     24m45.152s
```

You need 64 cores and 200 GB RAM (no swap) mounted as `tmpfs` to do this, but you can probably reproduce the effect with smaller hardware.

If you do not have GNU Parallel you can get similar numbers with:

```
time (
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M & 
wait
) > 100g

time (
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 1 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 2 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 3 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 4 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 5 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 6 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 7 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 8 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 9 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 10 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 11 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 12 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 13 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 14 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 15 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 16 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 17 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 18 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 19 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 20 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 21 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 22 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 23 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 24 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 25 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 26 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 27 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 28 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 29 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 30 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 31 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 32 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 33 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 34 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 35 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 36 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 37 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 38 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 39 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 40 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 41 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 42 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 43 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 44 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 45 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 46 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 47 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 48 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 49 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 50 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 51 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 52 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 53 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 54 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 55 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 56 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 57 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 58 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 59 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 60 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 61 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 62 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 63 &
yes $(seq 1000) | head -c 1600M > 64 &
wait
)
```

`tmpfs` is the default in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ uname -a
Linux r815 5.4.0-66-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 27 22:54:38 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ mount
tmpfs on /mnt/tmpfs type tmpfs (rw,noatime)
```

I am not sure if it helps us, but it seems something similar applies to HDD block devices:

```
# Read the full disk into cache
sudo pv /dev/sde >/dev/null
# Read the full disk again from cache
time sudo cat /dev/sde >/dev/null

real    1m20.100s
user    0m0.739s
sys     1m19.351s

# Read the full disk again from cache 64 times in parallel
seq 64 | time sudo parallel -N0 'cat /dev/sde >/dev/null'

297.64user 39359.17system 12:44.60elapsed 5186%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 19752maxresident)k
0inputs+8outputs (0major+117384minor)pagefaults 0swaps

# Read the full disk again from cache as 64 parts in parallel
time sudo parallel -a /dev/sde --pipepart --block -1 -u 'cat >/dev/null'
real    1m5.796s
user    0m13.331s
sys     67m34.396s
```

Comment: Is this the original `tmpfs`, or one of the clones from Linux/BSD/... ? What are the general constraints (amount of RAM, background storage, ...) for your test?

Comment: @PhilipCouling It is unclear to me how that would affect access to (different blocks of) a single file but not access to multiple files in parallel.

Comment: I'm hunting for a better reference that the one I just deleted, I'm not entirely comfortable with it.  The way I read it, the definable order of read and write can be implemented with a lock per file, so contention would occur for the same file but not different files.  But let me see if I can dig out a better reference or otherwise disprove the theory.. that last one was too shaky for my taste.

Comment: @OleTange If it is the original, you could try to use `dtrace` to analyze what happens.

Comment: See [All of the following functions shall be atomic with respect to each other in the effects specified in POSIX.1-2008 when they operate on regular files or symbolic links](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/functions/V2_chap02.html).  Read and write must be atomic.  I can't see how this could be implemented without a shared read-write lock per file since a read must be prevented from seeing half a write.  Separate file don't suffer the same constraint and can use different locks.  I haven't managed to locate it in source though.